# Typescript compile error: Property 'raw' does not exist on type 'typeof e' on express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I see a lot of examples where they use express.raw() or express.raw({type: 'application/json'}) on their requests as middleware... but .raw() doesn't exist on express, or does it?

I am using typescript and express: 4.16.4

```
Typescript compile error: Property 'raw' does not exist on type 'typeof e' on express
```

Answer (score 0):

`express.raw()` was introduced in version 4.17.0, see [Release Notes](https://github.com/expressjs/express/releases/tag/4.17.0).

By updating your express dependency you should be able to use the middleware.